# The dependency `AFNetworking (~> 2.5)` is not used in any concrete target

Tags: ios, xcode, git, afnetworking, cocoapods

I want to install AFNetworking but I have a problem, how can I fix and install? I used [Getting Started with AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) :

1. Download CocoaPods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

2.a. Create a Podfile

```
touch Podfile
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

2.b. And copy-paste this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Add:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
end
```

See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Then run `pod install` from the project directory.