# How to fix error with CocoaPods?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm learning iOS just now.
I cloned from https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat.git 
 and I build it but get error.

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: Manifest.lock: No such file or directory error: 
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.`
```

So I remove the workspace file and pod install.

```
rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace
pod install
```

But I met errors.

```
Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `Alamofire (~> 1.3)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `APAddressBook` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `Bolts` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `JSQMessagesViewController (from `https://github.com/galambalazs/JSQMessagesViewController.git`, branch `smooth-scrolling`)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `JSQSystemSoundPlayer` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `FBSDKCoreKit` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `FBSDKLoginKit` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `FBSDKShareKit` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `FBAudienceNetwork` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `Parse` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `ParseUI` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `ParseCrashReporting` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `ParseFacebookUtils` is not used in any concrete target.

[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.
```

The Podfile is :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3’
pod 'APAddressBook'
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git =>    'https://github.com/galambalazs/JSQMessagesViewController.git', :branch => 'smooth-scrolling'
pod 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'

pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: why did this get 3 upvotes ? and you need to use `use target` `do` according to the new cocoapod specification

Comment: Amateurism, dependency definitions should always include versions.

Comment: I don't know about this. I'm learning iOS just now. Can you kindly explain about this errors? I'll think grateful to your helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The dependency \`AFNetworking (~> 2.5)\` is not used in any concrete target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464977/the-dependency-afnetworking-2-5-is-not-used-in-any-concrete-target)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mr. Shubhank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the podfile like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SwiftParseChat' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3’
    pod 'APAddressBook'
    pod 'Bolts'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/galambalazs/JSQMessagesViewController.git', :branch => 'smooth-scrolling'
    pod 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer'

    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'

    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'ParseUI'
    pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
    pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
  # Pods for SwiftParseChat

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
rm Podfile
pod init
```

Then new Podfile is created.
Then you can insert necessary API to the new Podfile.