# The dependency `Firebase/Core` is not used in any concrete target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, podfile

I am using Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3, and IOS 10.2 (for iphone simulator). I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

I have not gotten to the Firebase stuff. Right now I am just trying to build and compile the starter code.

The starter Podfile looks like this:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

When I run pod install, I get

```
Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `Firebase/Core` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `Firebase/Database` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `Firebase/Auth` is not used in any concrete target.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you added this target to these dependencies? like, 

target 'your target' do

Comment: @Rajesh73 I am new to podfiles, how do I add target to dependencies?

Comment: According to the starter code, it should build and run as it comes?

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/37465219/4611751

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this might works for you

```
target "TARGET_NAME" do
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Database'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this works and the starter podfile does not (although it should)?

Comment: starter pod file doen't know your target name. Target name may be the different than you .xcodeproject file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my podfile for Firebase:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FirebaseUI'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by not specifying the target. You have to add the `target "your target name"` in Podfile.